# Comparing list values and removing from one list - Groovy/Java

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I’m writing some tests in groovy using spock where I need to check that the values in two equally sized lists with are correctly mapped to each other and that no duplicate values exist in one of the lists.
I’m currently doing the following:

I find a given value in list1 then I search for its corresponding value in list2. 
If I find that corresponding value in list2 I want to remove it. I repeat this to for every position on the list (list1) and at the end I want to verify that list2 is empty. If list2 is not empty at the end it indicates there were some unexpected values or duplicates which were not removed.

I’m doing the following

```
def list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
def list2 = ["dog", "goat", "wolf", "fox"]

list1.size() == list2.(size)

list1.size().times() {
 if (list1.contains("a")) {
  if (list2.contains("dog")) {
   println(it + " found dog.... removing")
   list2.remove("dog")
   println(list2)
  }
  if (list1.contains("b")) {
   if (list2.contains("goat")) {
    println(it + " found goat.... removing")
    list2.remove("goat")
    println(list2)
   }
  }
  if (list1.contains("c")) {
   if (list2.contains("wolf")) {
    println(it + " found wolf.... removing")
    list2.remove("wolf")
    println(list2)
   }
  }

  if (list1.contains("d")) {
  if (list2.contains("fox")) {
    println(it + " found fox.... removing")
    list2.remove("fox")
    println(list2)
   }
  }
 }
 }
list2.isEmpty()
```

This seems to work but im wondering if there is there a more effective way of doing this in groovy?

Comment: Are duplicates possible? E.g. there are two "a" in list1 and two "dog" in list2?

Comment: Please either accept & upvote my answer (or someone else's answer) or provide feedback if you have any follow-up questions or problems understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is very complicated.

The good thing about Spock is, you can split the assertions in multiple parts.

First check for correct mappings.
And then check for no additional mappings in the remaining lists.

```
then: 'correct mapping'
list1.remove("a") == list2.remove("dog")
list1.remove("b") == list2.remove("goat")
list1.remove("c") == list2.remove("wolf")
list1.remove("d") == list2.remove("fox")

and: 'no additional mapping'
list1.isEmpty()
list2.isEmpty()
```

Comment: Thanks Sven, I used this approach since my lists are not sorted and this accounts for the unsorted data

Answer (score 1):

It is actually even easier than described by Sven, just one line of code if you use the Groovy default method `transpose(List)` which actually maps to [`GroovyCollections.transpose(List)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.html#transpose(java.util.List)):

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q61859270

import spock.lang.Specification

class ListMappingTest extends Specification {
  static class UnderTest {
    List<String> getFirstList() {
      ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    }

    List<String> getSecondList() {
      ["dog", "goat", "wolf", "fox"]
    }
  }

  def "lists in matching order"() {
    given:
    def underTest = new UnderTest()
    def list1 = underTest.getFirstList()
    def list2 = underTest.getSecondList()

    expect: "one way to do it: list of lists"
    [list1, list2].transpose() ==
      [["a", "dog"], ["b", "goat"], ["c", "wolf"], ["d", "fox"]]

    and: "another way to do it: map"
    [list1, list2].transpose().collectEntries { [it[0], it[1]] } ==
      [a: "dog", b: "goat", c: "wolf", d: "fox"]
  }

  def "lists in non-matching order"() {
    given:
    def underTest = new UnderTest()
    def list1 = underTest.getFirstList().swap(0, 3)
    def list2 = underTest.getSecondList().swap(1, 2)
    def set1 = list1.toSet()
    def set2 = list2.toSet()

    expect:
    list1.size() == set1.size()
    list2.size() == set2.size()
    set1 == ["a", "b", "c", "d"].toSet()
    set2 == ["dog", "goat", "wolf", "fox"].toSet()
  }
}
```

Comment: That only works if the lists are "sorted". With list1 = ["d", "a", "b", "c"] this test would fail but the bobe_b's tests succeeds.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming sorted lists in the corresponding order for both cases. If this is not the case, _bobe_b_ can tell me. Until now I got no feedback yet.

Comment: I have updated my sample code in order to show (a) an alternative way to handle lists in matching order and (b) also another way to handle non-matching order. I think it is a matter of taste whether to use @SvenDöring's style or mine. Mine might be a little more compact for longer lists.

Comment: Both test methods do not work in case one or more items are missing in the lists.

Comment: So? My tests verify that all pairs are there, no more and no fewer. This is exactly the purpose. Of course the tests fail if the conditions are not being met.

Comment: Look at bobe_b test. His test does not fail if there is one or more item missing in both lists.

Comment: The requirements are unclear and we are wasting time speculating here, because the OP does not give any feedback. My goal was not to reproduce the original test results but to write tests checking what I understood was the required behaviour. Let's stop debating, shall we? It is unproductive with fuzzy requirements like these.